# vim change multiline html tags with vim-surround

Tags: plugin-vim-surround

I would like, using vim-surround to convert this

```
            <p>
            ^currsor
              Issues reported by users from the
              <a href="https://re.fr"> https://re.fr</a>
              they will create an issue.
            </p>
```

into that

```
            <h1>
              Issues reported by users from the
              <a href="https://re.fr"> https://re.fr</a>
              they will create an issue.
            </h1>
```

I've been using in command mode: `cs<<h1>` and I get

```
            <h1>p</h1>
            ^currsor
              Issues reported by users from the
              <a href="https://re.fr"> https://re.fr</a>
              they will create an issue.
            </p>
```

from: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65908860/vim-change-multiline-html-tags-with-vim-surround

Comment: I experimented with it a little bit... It looks like `cst<h1>` using `t` instead of `<` helps, though in my case it reindents the block as well. It looks like `<` was supposed to be a synonym for `t`, but they don't seem to behave the same... Still not 100% sure of what's happening here.

Comment: The thing is, the text-object `i<` actually use the part inside the brackets (the `p` part of the tag), so that could be related.

Answer (score 1):

Without using surround with just vanilla vim8 I got this

`vat` this select the block including the `p` tag then I call

```
:'<,'>s/p>/h1>/
```

and I got (by the way it does not break the indentation):

```html
            <h1>                                                                                    
              Issues reported by users from the                                                     
              <a href="https://re.fr"> https://re.fr</a>                                            
              they will create an issue.                                                            
            </h1>
```